# Measures for the code that prevents iFrame execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to implement iFrames, but this pagination code gets in the way.
If I don't comment out this pagination code, iFrame will not be executed.

pagination code ( [pagination.js](https://pagination.js.org/) ):

```
//////////  this part or ↓
function tpl(data) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(data, function(index,item) {
      html += '<section class="item">' + item + '</section>';
  });
  return html;
}
//////////

$(function() {
  var len = $('.item').length;

  $('#no-p').pagination({
    dataSource: function(done) {
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var $item = $('.item').get(i);
        if ($item) result.push($item.innerHTML);
      }
      done(result);
    },
    pageSize: 8,
    showPageNumbers: false,
    showNavigator: true,
    autoHidePrevious: true,
    autoHideNext: true,

    //////////  iFrame will not be executed unless this part is deleted ↓
    callback: function(data,pagination) {
      var html = tpl(data);
      $('#items').html(html);
    }
    //////////

  });
});
```

iFrame code ( [iziModal.js](http://izimodal.marcelodolce.com/) ):

```
$(document).on('click', '.item1', function (event) {
  $(".item1").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe').iziModal('open');
    $('#modal').iziModal('open', {
      iframeURL: $(this).data('href')
    });
  });
  $("#modal").iziModal({
    iframe: true,
    width: '98%',
    iframeHeight: 650,
    zindex: '110',
    iframeURL: "data.html",
    group: 'works',
    overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
  });
  $(".item1").off('click');
});
```

However, I need **both** iFrame and pagination.

How can I implement both?

Comment: Please define what "gets in the way" means. What is the expected behavior? What is the actual observed behavior? What error messages do you get? Is there a JSFiddle or CodeSandbox that you can link to that shows the problem?

Comment: Do you have HTML or do you expect us to guess?

Comment: @Patrick Hund, zer00ne I'm sorry, I found a reply now by a bug in my wifi environment.
I'll create a demo that I can actually see in JSFiddle or some other way.

However, there have stuff to do after this, so it will be a few hours later.. sorry! x(

Comment: @Patrick Hund, zer00ne I was late. I created a demo here. Please look at the here -> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/41kLsf67/49/)